# SCM URL of local GIT repo

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to test mvn release plugin with my local git repo . I am getting error 
**No SCM URL was provided to perform the release from** even though parent pom has following detail

```
<scm>
    <url>scm:git:file://localhost/d/Research/Research.git</url>
    <connection>scm:git:file://localhost/d/Research/Research.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:file://localhost/d/Research/Research.git</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

Is this correct way to define local repo in mvn ?

Comment: that looks correct according to https://maven.apache.org/scm/git.html - is the .git suffix the problem? url is usually just a link with no provider information: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#SCM

Comment: @wemu , .git should be there . I checked my project's pom ( which is working with actual remote git repo ) have .git in the url.

Comment: well remotes do. but you point to a local directory. not that this path resolution does not behave the same way as a git server. just as an experiment :)

Comment: Thanks for your input @wemu . Managed to get it working.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally managed to get it working . As I am on windows I used below scm tag

```
<scm>
  <url>scm:git:file://d:/Research/.git</url>
  <connection>scm:git:file://d:/Research/.git</connection>
  <developerConnection>scm:git:file://d:/Research/.git</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

Thanks @wemu for your inputs.

Comment: please accept your own answer if its working, so others see the question is answered :)